# how to make this bool in my c# program work

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming, basically, as you will be able to see everything works up until I want to ask if the details are correct, whatever I type in it will always take the details as correct, I want to be able to type yes or no to the confirmation. I would really appreciate someone explain this to me so i can use bools properly

```
namespace UserFeedBack.cs
{
    class MainClass
    {    
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Console.Write("Enter your name : ");
            string Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hey there, " +Name );
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("How old are you : ");
            string Age = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" Hello " + Name + " you are " + Age + "!");
            Console.Write("bank card account number :");
            string AccountNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you! to confirm, is your account number : " + AccountNumber);
            Console.ReadLine();
            bool y = true;

            if (y) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you, we can confirm your details are correct");
            }

            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("re enter your details : ");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: You define a variable `y` and you set it to `true`. Then you have an `if` where you check whether `y` is `true`. Of course y is true. Since you only set `y` to true, `y` will always be true...

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask)?, and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)?

Comment: You'll need to set a variable to the result of the last `Console.ReadLine()`, much as you did a couple of lines before with `AccountNumber`. You'll then want to figure out how to parse the response as either true or false, then use that result.

Comment: That said trying to learn how to program by trial-error on [so] is not going to be good for you or for anyone answering your questions. Instead I recommend you start by learning how to debug your code in an IDE (like visual studio) and do things like inspect variables and program state. That will allow you to answer many of your initial questions on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared your bool property `bool y = true;`, and doing that sets the value of the bool to be always true. what you need to do is evaluate what the user is typing with `Console.ReadLine()`. If the user type "Yes" then you change the property to true, else you change it to false, like this:

```
class MainClass
    {    
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Console.Write("Enter your name : ");
            string Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hey there, " +Name );
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("How old are you : ");
            string Age = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" Hello " + Name + " you are " + Age + "!");
            Console.Write("bank card account number :");
            string AccountNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you! to confirm, is your account number : " + AccountNumber);
            bool confirmed = Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "yes";

            if (confirmed) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you, we can confirm your details are correct");
            }

            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("re enter your details : ");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```